# Bug: Select2 Ajax Multiselect Checkbox Does't Delete (Deselect) When You Double Click(Toggle) On Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-select2, multi-select

This is Select2 library

Checkbox normally works after double clicks. It carries out the Add and Delete operation.

But when I use the ajax multiselect checkbox, it can add but I cannot delete it through select.

When I want to delete, I can only delete it by pressing x on the top.

This is my code : **https://codepen.io/tolga-kurtulu/pen/KKaOVXp?editors=1011**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWi3L.png)

HTML

```
   <select class="select2" style="width: 100%;" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.select2").select2({
        closeOnSelect: false,
        placeholder: "Placeholderr",
        // allowHtml: true,
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true,
        // debug: true,
    ajax: {
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: (params) => {
        return {
          q: params.term,
        }
      },
      processResults: (data, params) => {
        const results = data.items.map(item => {
          return {
            id: item.id,
            text: item.full_name || item.name,
          };
        });
        return {
          results: results,
        }
      },
    },
  });
})
```